# You are using Stripe.js in live mode over an insecure connection

Tags: payment-processor, 4.6.2, stripe

Testing out Stripe with Civicrm 4.6.2, the plugin installed from [Civicrm Stripe payment processor](https://github.com/drastik/com.drastikbydesign.stripe), when confirming the input test data of a Contribution Campaign with an enabled thank you page, stripe.js replies with:

```
You are using Stripe.js in live mode over an insecure connection.
This is considered unsafe. Please conduct live requests only on sites 
served over https.
```

Now the Stripe dashboard is set to test, yet even after caching and reloading the page this message is shown.

Possibly for this reason when submitting a payment with a test card there is no confirmation, the page just renders again with the blank payment details input form. Nothing is shown on the Stripe dashboard.
What could the problem be?

**UPDATE:**

After setting the Link to Test-Drive, the process works in the dashboard admin. On the live site after submitting the transaction with the details, the page still renders again with blank cc input form. In the console there are two errors which I think might be the reason for the error:

```
TypeError: cont is undefined civicrm:1460
ReferenceError: Shadowbox is not defined civicrm:1509
```

Shadowbox JS is installed as a plugin and set to active. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Not only must the stripe dashboard be "test" but CiviCRM's contribution page must be rendered in "test drive" mode as well.   Is that the case?

[image]

Comment: Hi @civicteacher, so I did now change the links to Test-Drive, I can only process one test payment from within the admin dashboard. When I go to the page on the site, enter cc details and then submit, again the same blank form is displayed without bringing me to "make contribution" (as it does in the admin panel).
 Do you have any idea why that is?

Comment: Please post the actual links to the pages you are attempting to process.  Unless the URL contains the phrase "action=preview" and there is a large message at the top of the civicrm page about "test drive mode" you are not actually processing in test drive mode